# avoiding donload limit using wget

Tags: python, download, wget

I need to download several webpages from the web. I am using wget(URL) to download them but I am finding that after a certain amount of download (less than 100s) it does not download and gives error.

Can anyone tells what's the best way to download many webpages whose URLs I have in a file.

```
Query1='"http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22'+a+'%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C24"'
        URL1='wget --user-agent Chrome '+Query1+' -O '+file1
        os.system(URL1)
```

This is the code that I am using

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting an empty file 0KB file

Comment: the cmd says that the file is unavailable or unable to resolve...

Comment: First, why call out to the system to get the pages when there are 4+ libraries to do GETs natively in Python?  Second, you are probably hitting a traffic limit on Google Scholar that is there specifically to keep people from flooding them with requests.  Look at their terms of service.

Comment: I'd suggest `requests` if you have a choice of method to download the files. `import requests; r = requests.get("http://url"); r.text`